# Meteor 0.6.5 update: underscore error

Tags: meteor, underscore.js

I recently updated my meteor app to 0.6.5 and I noticed that the underscore package not working anymore.
The error log is:

```
W20130814-20:31:26.431(-3)? (STDERR) /home/mariano/.meteor/tools/4010e5731d/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20130814-20:31:26.494(-3)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20130814-20:31:26.494(-3)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20130814-20:31:26.494(-3)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: _ is not defined
W20130814-20:31:26.496(-3)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/meteor-file/meteor-file.js:92)
W20130814-20:31:26.496(-3)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor-file.js:120:4
W20130814-20:31:26.496(-3)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor-file.js:127:3
W20130814-20:31:26.496(-3)? (STDERR)     at mains (/home/mariano/borrar/blocnotas/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:153:10)
W20130814-20:31:26.497(-3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20130814-20:31:26.497(-3)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/mariano/.meteor/tools/4010e5731d/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20130814-20:31:26.497(-3)? (STDERR)     at /home/mariano/borrar/blocnotas/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

If you're using an atmosphere (i.e. mrt) package, you may need to downgrade to 0.6.4.1 until the package author has had a chance to update to the new package API that is part of 0.6.5. You can find instructions here - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-talk/BbrjGcGGIzc/discussion

Hope that helps!

Comment: a lot of thanks for your quick response!, but i follow instructions and I still have an error with underscore.

Comment: Did you also edit your ".meteor/packages" file to remove the "standard-app-packages" line? (This is in the linked instructions, but easy to overlook.) Also, are you getting the same error that you posted here, and was the underscore package definitely working before you updated?

If you're positive you've followed the instructions exactly, I recommend posting about your problem in that thread I linked. I also recommend contacting the package author to see if they are planning to push a 0.6.5 compatibility fix soon.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your (or someone else's) `meteor-file.js` package needs to register an explicit dependency for underscore. This was included automatically in versions prior to 0.6.5. Add the following in `package.js`:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use('underscore', 'server');
});
```